# Rails 6 with multiple database, auto change connection based on read or create query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, database-connection

The question might be **silly** and it's not practiced in real world. Anyway kindly give your thoughts/pros/cons....

Lets say I am having two database **read replica database** and **master database**

**Scenario 1:**

`Model.all` # It should query from read replica database

**Scenario 2:**

`Model.create(attributes)` # It should create data in master database

**Scenario 3:**

`Model.where(condition: :some_condition).update(attributes)` # It should read data from replica database and update the data in master database

Note: In runtime database should detect the query and process the above 3 scenario.

Questions:

1. Is this a valid expectation?
2. if Yes, How to achieve this case completely or partially?
3. if No, What wrong in this case and what issues we will be facing?

Answer (score 2):

Rails 6 provides a framework for auto-routing incoming requests to either the primary database connection, or a read replica.

By default, this new functionality allows your app to automatically route read requests (GET, HEAD) to a read-relica database if it has been at least 2 seconds since the last write request (any request that is not a GET or HEAD request) was made.

The logic that specifies when a read request should be routed to a replica is specified in a resolver class, `ActiveRecord::Middleware::DatabaseSelector::Resolver` by default, which you would override if you wanted custom behavior.

The middleware also provides a session class, `ActiveRecord::Middleware::DatabaseSelector::Resolver::Session` that is tasked with keeping track of when the last write request was made. Like the resolver, this class can also be overridden.

To enable the default behavior, you would add the following configuration options to one of your app's environment files - `config/environments/production.rb` for example:

```
config.active_record.database_selector = { delay: 2.seconds }
config.active_record.database_resolver = 
  ActiveRecord::Middleware::DatabaseSelector::Resolver
config.active_record.database_operations = 
  ActiveRecord::Middleware::DatabaseSelector::Resolver::Session
```

If you decide to override the default functionality, you can use these configuration options to specify the delay you'd like to use, the name of your custom resolver class, and the name of your custom session class, both of which should be descendants of the default classes

Comment: Thanks for the answer, the auto switching can work in HTTP verbs/REST Api calls to rails application. Basically middleware will take care of auto switching by keeping read/write session in database or cookies. But my questions is different, with in model or for simplicity within rails console if I try the actual scenarios in the question, will it work? if not how to achieve that?

Comment: Upvoted your answer, as it will definitely help others :)

Comment: @Jak in rails 6.1.3.2 you can do something like this https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_multiple_databases.html#setting-up-your-application